# From a List representation of a Map, to a real Map in Scala

Tags: algorithm, scala, functional-programming

I want to transform a Seq of keys/values to a Map. The first element of the sequence is reserved, so **the list of pairs starts in the position 1**.

The question is: Is possible to implement this function using a more functional way?

```
def list2Map(plainMap:Seq[String]) = {
  var map = Map[String, String]()
  var idx = 1;
  while(plainMap.size > idx) {
    val key = plainMap(idx)
    idx += 1
    val value = plainMap(idx)
    idx += 1

    map = map + (key -> value)
  }

  map
}

assert( list2Map( Seq("reserved slot","key0","value0","key1","value1","key2","value2") ) == Map( ("key0"->"value0"),("key1"->"value1"),("key2"->"value2") ) )
```

I am new in Scala, and I know that there are a lot of different ways to iterate over a collection, but I don't found a forEach way to read two elements per iteration, starting in the element 1.

PS: Thanks folks. I am learning a lot with everyone response!!

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: @Dima The question is If it is possible to implement this function in a more functional way.  I updated the question.

Comment: Can you provide a sample input and expected output? Just giving a simple example may well provide enough details to get an answer.

Comment: @KevinMeredith The last line is the assertion of the example (input data and expected output)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`list.drop(1).grouped(2).map { x => x.head -> x.last }.toMap`

Comment: One might prefer to have a `.filter(_.length == 2)` after the `grouped(2)` so that if there was a trailing key with no value, it'd be ignored.  This code sets the value equal to the key in the case of a trailing key.

Answer (score 2):

You mean something like this?:

```
val list = List("reserved slot", "key0", "value0", "key1", "value1", "key2", "value2")
val list4Map = list.tail.grouped(2).map { listBy2 => (listBy2(0), listBy2(1)) }.toList

val map = Map(list4Map: _*)
```

Comment: Good one. I prefer the version of @Dima because is using the .toMap directly. Is there any reason to use .toList and create a map in the next step? Thx!

Comment: The `grouped` method returns and `Iterator` of lists, and you can't pass that to `Map` factory method, it needs a `Seq[Tuple2[A,B]]`, so I added `toList`. Indeed, there are many ways to achieve your goal, that's why Scala is so flexible... :) and fun! :D

Comment: Thx! Yes, it is incredible flexible and fun. I am starting to fall in love. :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you would like some recursive one:

```
def seq2Map[T](seq: Seq[T]) = {
  def rec(seq: Seq[T], map: Map[T,T] = Map.empty[T,T]): Map[T,T] = seq match {
    case h :: t :: e => rec(e, map + (h -> t))
    case _ => map
  }
  rec(seq.tail)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(for { Seq(k, v) <- list.tail.grouped(2) } yield k -> v).toMap
```

covers trailing key too

Comment: What if `val list = Vector("ignored", "fish", "wish", "dish")`?  I think `List(k, v)` needs to be `Seq(k, v)`.