# Decompress delta compressed sequence of numbers in Scala

Tags: algorithm, scala, functional-programming

Yesterday, I asked about [From a List representation of a Map, to a real Map in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37932216/from-a-list-representation-of-a-map-to-a-real-map-in-scala)

After few really smart response, I know that it is necessary change my mind to work in Scala and I am sure that stackoverflow is the way.

In this occasion, I want to decompress a sequence of number stored using delta compression.
I think that my implementation is really simple, but I am sure that you guys are going to find other more functional way.

```
def deltaDecompression(compressed : Seq[Long]) = {
  var previous = 0L
  compressed.map(current => {
    previous += current
    previous
  })
}

assert(deltaDecompression(Seq(100,1,2,3)) == Seq(100,101,103,106))
```

So like in my previous question, the question is: **Is possible to implement this function using a more functional way?**

Example input data and expected output in the last line of the code, as an assertion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`compressed.scanLeft(0l) { _ + _ }.drop(1)`

Comment: again. you are great :) But there is an error: 
Expression of type*Int,Long)=>Long doesn't conform to expected type (Int,Long)=>Int

Comment: Yeah ... I'll leave for you to figure out yourself, as an exercise ;)

Comment: `tail` may look cleaner

Comment: @VictorMoroz not sure I understand what is it that you find particularly "dirty" about `drop` :)

Comment: @Dima One hour to find the response: The initial value is an Int, so the expected response in the function is an Int. So:
compressed.scanLeft(0L) { _ + _ }.drop(1)
Is it right?

Comment: Nice usage of `scanLeft`. I respectfully suggest adding `val compressed = Seq(100,1,2,3)` to make it clear what `compressed` is.

Comment: @angelcervera yes, you got it :)